# Not unique table/alias

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1066

I get the error `ERROR 1066 (42000): Not unique table/alias:`

I cant figure out whats wrong with it.

```
SELECT Project_Assigned.ProjectID, Project_Title, Account.Account_ID, Username, Access_Type
FROM Project_Assigned 
JOIN Account 
  ON Project_Assigned.AccountID = Account.Account_ID
JOIN Project
  ON Project_Assigned.ProjectID = Project.Project_ID
where Access_Type = 'Client';
```

Comment: You should post the table schemas. You are throwing in many columns without a reference to their table, which is OK if the columns are unique. However, I would suggest you start aliasing the table names, and always prefix the columns with the table alias when you are joining. It might sound naive, but are you sure this is the query producing that error? Have you tried to run the query directly into the mysql console or phpMyAdmin?

Comment: I always execute the mysql query in terminal via mysql console and I've tried to fix it enough times to know this is the error its executing.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Your query contains columns which could be present with the same name in more than one table you are referencing, hence the not unique error. It's best if you make the references explicit and/or use table aliases when joining.

Try

```
    SELECT pa.ProjectID, p.Project_Title, a.Account_ID, a.Username, a.Access_Type, c.First_Name, c.Last_Name
      FROM Project_Assigned pa
INNER JOIN Account a
        ON pa.AccountID = a.Account_ID
INNER JOIN Project p
        ON pa.ProjectID = p.Project_ID
INNER JOIN Clients c
        ON a.Account_ID = c.Account_ID
     WHERE a.Access_Type = 'Client';
```

Comment: @Shef - Do you have more information about why table aliases are required in this query? I haven't been able to reproduce the error message here with MySQL 5.0 :-?

Comment: Something to note. Aparently I'm using MySQL 5.5.9

Comment: On top of the query that works above how do I get the clients first_name, Last_Name from a separete Client table with the same Account_ID?

Comment: Hi Álvaro perhaps because of the two joins - `JOIN Account 
  ON Project_Assigned.AccountID = Account.Account_ID
JOIN Project
  ON Project_Assigned.ProjectID = Project.Project_ID`  with them, the compiler doesn't know which tables are being referred because fields like "ProjectID" are not unique - they could come from either of the tables so the compiler might be complaining rather than guessing... unless you use aliases :)  Rule of thumb, use aliases whenever joining and be explicit in references.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario: I am guessing the OP had another table, which was conflicting.

Comment: Shef why did you remove proj.ProjectID = 1 from the code? Please ignore Access_Type. Its Client.First_Name and Client.Last_Name I am trying to implement into the resultset of your origional code so when sql outputs the table containing the users Account_ID I would also like to see their first name and last name.

Comment: Down-voted! To help others learn, always add a comment and explain why your solution worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
 select persons.personsid,name,info.id,address
    -> from persons
    -> inner join persons on info.infoid = info.info.id;
```

Comment: Please have a look at [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) and update your answer to provide more detail. Specifically, it would be helpful if you explained how this solves the problem

Answer (score 0):

I had this error, and the cause was an incorrect string concatenation. I was joining two sql string and forgot to put a space between them.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32512584)