# Third join to get first_Name and Last_Name of account

Tags: mysql

I have the following query which matches `Account_ID`'s on Accounts table with the `AccountID`'s on project assigned table and displays the accounts assigned to a project:

```
SELECT proj.ProjectID, A.Project_Title, B.Account_ID, B.Username, B.Access_Type
FROM Project_Assigned proj
INNER JOIN Account B
    ON proj.AccountID = B.Account_ID
INNER JOIN Project A
    ON proj.ProjectID = A.Project_ID
WHERE proj.ProjectID = 1;
```

What I want to do now is get the `First_Name`, Last_Name from Client table and Agency_Employee table and display the information matched against the `Account_ID`'s. Both `Client_ID` and `Employee_ID` are foreign keys of `Account_ID`. How would I add this information into the join above?

I have attempted to add an additional join but I always get a result set match 0 which I know shouldn't be the case.

Client Table:

```
+-----------+------------+-----------+
| Client_ID | First_Name | Last_Name |
+-----------+------------+-----------+
|         4 | Phil       | Jones     |
+-----------+------------+-----------+
```

Employee Table:

```
+-------------+------------+-----------+
| Employee_ID | First_Name | Last_Name |
+-------------+------------+-----------+
|           2 | John       | Smith     |
|           5 | Bob        | Jones     |
|           6 | Fred       | Tucker    |
+-------------+------------+-----------+
```

Account Table:

```
+------------+----------+
| Account_ID | Username |
+------------+----------+
|          1 | Dan      |
|          2 | rjm      |
|          3 | pw       |
|          4 | Philly   |
|          5 | bob      |
|          6 | fred     |
+------------+----------+
```

Project Assigned Table:

```
+-----------+-----------+
| ProjectID | AccountID |
+-----------+-----------+
|         1 |         1 |
|         1 |         2 |
|         1 |         4 |
+-----------+-----------+
```

Comment: What is the mapping between client table, employee table and account

Comment: The Account_ID in Account table has a 1-1 relationship with the Employee_ID in employee table as well as a 1-1 from Account.Account_ID to Client_ID in client table.

Comment: Could you change your example not to use cryptic table aliaes A and B?  What's wrong with the existing table names Account and Project?

Comment: I was getting errors, aliases were neccasary see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8084571/not-unique-table-alias

Comment: Don't know about that, looks like a different problem - those table names are unique anyway.

Comment: Can you also supply an example of the other tables?  They're kind of important too. `Project` and `Project_Assigned`.  And also an example of what you expect to see - it's hard to guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure, but you seem to indicate that for an Account with ID 5, the Client will have ID 5 and the Employee will have ID 5?  Slightly odd, and you probably want to read up on normalisation, but shouldn't this work?

```
SELECT 
    proj.ProjectID, 
    Project.Project_Title, 
    Account.Account_ID, Account.Username,
    Client.First_Name AS Client_First_Name, Client.Last_Name AS Client_Last_Name,
    Employee.First_Name AS Employee_First_Name, Employee.Last_Name AS Employee_Last_Name

FROM `Project_Assigned` proj
INNER JOIN `Account` ON (proj.AccountID = Account.Account_ID)
INNER JOIN `Project` ON (proj.ProjectID = Project.Project_ID)
LEFT JOIN `Client` ON (Account.Account_ID = Client.Client_ID)
LEFT JOIN `Employee` ON (Account.Account_ID = Employee.Employee_ID)
WHERE proj.ProjectID = 1;
```

**edit**
Okay, I've updated my answer.
You'll have two first names and two lastnames, one of each will always be null.

If you only want one contact name, try this:

```
SELECT 
    COALESCE(Client.First_Name, Employee.First_Name) FirstName,
    COALESCE(Client.Last_Name, Employee.Last_Name) LastName
```

Comment: No, Account ID's should be unique among client and employee. The unique ID's correspond to either client or employee. Never both. ProjectID in project_assigned table is what assosiates accounts with a project.

Comment: Like I commented above, you've missed examples of the most important tables of all.  Show us a Project_Assigned example and a Project example please.

Comment: Wait, so you link Account_ID to both Employee _and_ Client?  But it will only ever match one of them?  So your ID's in `Employee` might go 1,2,5,6,8 and your IDs in `Client` would then be 3,4,7,9?

Comment: Theres no pattern in the assignment of ID's if a new employee is created they are added to the accounts table and given an auto incremented ID from the Accounts table. Information about the Employee is added to the employee table and their ID from the Account_ID must match that created in the Account table. This applies the same for Client. I have uploaded scehema here below. Maybe restructuring the schema is in order? http://imagine-that.co.uk/other/a.png

Comment: Hmm, okay, that makes a bit more sense then.  So per that design, you can only have one Employee per account, as the Account ID _is_ the Employee ID.  I've updated my answer above, that should give what you want.  Is it possible that you'll one day have an Employee that is also a Client?  Or the same client at different accounts?  If so, you might want to normalise your "Clients" and "Employees" into a "People" table.  Gets more complex though, as you'll need a new join table to handle the many-to-many relationship. https://gist.github.com/1358596

Comment: Clients will never be Agency_Employees if that happened then there wouldent really be any need for the application. However clients can be general employees of another company but they arent associated with the agency. I could cover all eventualities but as you said it gets a lot more complex then. I have tried using your suggestion which I see no problem with but it outputs'Project.Project_Title, 
    Account.Account_ID, Account.Username,
    Client'. I see no problem with it so I'm scratching my head a little.

Comment: Something wonky with your query browser? :)  I just pasted it into MySQL Workbench and it seems okay.  Good luck, I have to leave the office now.  (I linked all my SQL in the previous comment btw)

Comment: What mySQL version are you running? Ive been having problem with the latest version which I recently downloaded from MAMP.

Comment: Got it working. It was the extra spaces causing the error. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT c.First_Name, c.Last_Name, e.First_Name, e.Last_Name 
FROM client c, employee e, account a 
WHERE c.Client_ID = a.Account_ID OR e.Employee_ID = a.Account_ID
```

OR

```
SELECT c.First_Name, c.Last_Name
FROM client c, account a 
WHERE c.Client_ID = a.Account_ID    
UNION    
SELECT e.First_Name, e.Last_Name 
FROM employee e, account a 
WHERE e.Employee_ID = a.Account_ID
```

Comment: But how would I combine this with the above query containing joins?

Comment: Again it easy to do as a separete query but I dont know the correct syntax required to add the above into the origional query's resultset.