# LEFT JOIN "Not unique table/alias"

Tags: mysql, left-join

I want to load all the posts and its tags with one query from my database.
I think LEFT JOIN is the appropriate one for that, do you have any other suggestion?
Here is my SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM posts, tags, tags_map 
LEFT JOIN posts on posts.cid = tags_map.pid 
WHERE tags.tag_id = tags_map.tid
```

It showing an error `Not unique table/alias: 'posts'` where is wrong, cause i am pointing to a table named 'posts', any idea?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Not unique table/alias](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8084571/not-unique-table-alias)

Comment: nah .. your pointed question is not same ... my bla bla bla ;)

Answer (score 2):

Remove posts table from "FROM" section:

```
SELECT * FROM tags, tags_map 
LEFT JOIN posts on posts.cid = tags_map.pid 
WHERE tags.tag_id = tags_map.tid
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not mix old and new style joins.  In fact, always use explicit `join` syntax.  Never use commas in the `from` clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM posts p JOIN
     tags_map tm
     ON p.cid = tm.pid JOIN
     tags t
     ON t.tag_id = tm.tid;
```

I'm not sure what the `left join` is for.  If you really need it, add it to this version of the query.

Comment: Thanks @GordonLinoff i have edited the post please take a look

Comment: @meh-_- . . . You have changed the question, after it was answered, which is impolite.  That can invalidate answers and draw downvotes.  If you have another question, then ask another question.

Comment: Ok, really sorry for that i am deleting the edit and going to create a new thread. :)