# JOIN two tables that share a common grandparent, but not parent

Tags: mysql, join, left-join, inner-join

I'm trying to unpack a layout system that organizes images and text like so:

[image: layout]

With the challenge being that I need to (somehow) associate each `text.content` with both its entry AND the first `images.filename` that *follows* it. Essentially introduce second cousins.

Ideally, I'd get something like :

```
| entry.id  | images.filename  | texts.content
|-----------|------------------|--------------
| 0         | img.jpg          | lorem
```

I've previously been successful at associating the images with their entry using a series of `LEFT JOIN`s like so:

```sql
SELECT entries.id, images.filename 
FROM images 
LEFT JOIN containers 
    ON images.container_id = containers.id 
LEFT JOIN layers 
    ON containers.layer_id = layers.id 
LEFT JOIN entries 
    ON layers.entry_id = entries.id
```

But this doesn't work when trying to connect the texts to images, because they aren't directly associated.  You have to go up to the entry level to determine association, but how do you then keep track of best-candidate for closest image?

### Currently

I feel like I'm closing in on something that will at least associate the images and texts to the same entry with:

```sql
SELECT entries.id, images.filename, texts.content
FROM entries, images, texts
LEFT JOIN containers a 
    ON texts.container_id = a.id 
LEFT JOIN containers b
    ON images.container_id = b.id 
LEFT JOIN layers 
    ON containers.layer_id = layers.id 
LEFT JOIN entries 
    ON layers.entry_id = entries.id
```

Though this is still kicking back a `Not unique table/alias: 'entries'` for some reason.

Thusfar I've tried the aliasing stuff suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8084571/not-unique-table-alias) (which doesn't really seem to apply)  and began hacking at [questions dealing with subqueries](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10485/multiple-left-joins-or-subquery) but ... I've run out of search terms.

### Is this even possible?

To be clear, I'm not looking for a whole answer here, just some hints as to how I might use JOINs to do the following:

A) Display texts and images and their entry associations ( I think I'm close here.)

B) **Associate one text entry with data from whatever image entry follows it.**. This feels like an impossibility right now, but I guess that's why I'm asking people who know more than I do.

**EDIT : Note that there can be multiple layers containing either images or texts and I need to return *all* texts from each entry.**

Comment: How do you determine a particular container contains image or text ? Does one of the id(s) in these tables have a fixed value for either image or text ?

Comment: Madhur Bhaiya : The containers don't know what they contain - their ids are just referenced by their children (images or texts).

Comment: Then, are you ensuring that same `id` value does not occur in image and text table ?

Answer (score 2):

looking to you schema seems you could try using a fake aggregation function based on a union for select filename and text

```sql
SELECT id, max(filename) filename, max(content) content 
FROM (
    SELECT entries.id, images.filename, NULL content
    FROM entries
        INNER JOIN layers 
            ON entries.id  = layers.entry_id
        INNER JOIN containers 
            ON containers.layer_id = layers.id
        INNER JOIN images 
            ON images.container_id = containers.id
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT entries.id, NULL, texts.content
    FROM entries
        INNER JOIN layers 
            on entries.id  = layers.entry_id
        INNER JOIN containers 
            on containers.layer_id = layers.id
        INNER JOIN texts 
        ON texts.container_id = containers.id ) t
GROUP BY id
```

Comment: This looks like it worked initially, but it returns only one text from each entry. Leaving the upvote because it's definitely closer than I was.

Comment: if you need  more then one entry you cant'use a single sql quer .. you must work with  a procedural langue and search using two distinct sql query ..one for filename and one for text content .. and merge the result al presentation level  ..