# SQL Query, JOIN and CASE statement giving errors

Tags: mysql, sql

My query works until I add the JOIN and WHERE statements. I need to JOIN the id from another table so I can filter only the rows I want. Any advice? Help is appreciated.

Error: #1066 - Not unique table/alias: 'ahv9t_facileforms_subrecords'

```
     SELECT
record,
MAX(CASE WHEN title = 'Listing ID' then value END) AS Listing,
MAX(CASE WHEN title = 'Status' then value END) AS Status,
MAX(CASE WHEN title = 'Resort' then value END) AS Resort,
MAX(CASE WHEN title = 'Points on Deed' then value END) AS Points,
MAX(CASE WHEN title = 'Use Year' then value END) AS UseYear,
MAX(CASE WHEN title = 'Points on Deed' then value END) AS Points,
MAX(CASE WHEN title = 'Last Years Points' then value END) AS LastYearPoints,
MAX(CASE WHEN title = 'This Years Points' then value END) AS ThisYearPoints,
MAX(CASE WHEN title = 'Next Years Points' then value END) AS NextYearPoints,
MAX(CASE WHEN title = 'Points Available' then value END) AS PointsAvailable,
MAX(CASE WHEN title = 'Price Per Point' then value END) AS PricePerPoint,
MAX(CASE WHEN title = 'Price' then value END) AS Price,
MAX(CASE WHEN title = 'Closing Cost' then value END) AS ClosingCost,
MAX(CASE WHEN title = 'Annual Dues at Closing' then value END) AS AnnualDuesAtClosing,
MAX(CASE WHEN title = 'Total Cost' then value END) AS TotalCost,
MAX(CASE WHEN title = 'Direct Price Per Point' then value END) AS DirectPricePerPoint,
MAX(CASE WHEN title = 'Savings' then value END) AS Savings,
MAX(CASE WHEN title = 'Contract Expires' then value END) AS ContractExpires,
MAX(CASE WHEN title = 'Current Annual Fees' then value END) AS CurrentAnnualFees
FROM ahv9t_facileforms_subrecords
JOIN ahv9t_facileforms_subrecords ON ahv9t_facileforms_records.id = ahv9t_facileforms_subrecords.record
WHERE ahv9t_facileforms_records.form = '12'
GROUP BY record
```

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, what do you mean? Also, it looks like you shouldn't have those `ELSE` clauses

Comment: I was following a youtube tutorial on the CASE statement. They didn't specify and can be removed if not necessary.
The error I am receiving is: #1066 - Not unique table/alias: 'ahv9t_facileforms_subrecords'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Not unique table/alias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8084571/not-unique-table-alias)

Comment: See about table aliases, and seriously consider handling issues of data display in application code

Comment: I have updated my question and am looking into the link.

Comment: Looks like `FROM ahv9t_facileforms_subrecords
JOIN ahv9t_facileforms_subrecords ` should maybe be `FROM ahv9t_facileforms_records
JOIN ahv9t_facileforms_subrecords`?

Comment: @Morten yes. I was playing with it when I copy and pasted. I pasted the wrong version. Was just testing the waters. I am still pretty fresh to all of this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after I fixed the JOIN section. It gave me a column 'title' is ambiguous error. So I added the table name in front of "title=" for each of my columns/rows. That fixed it. Now I am getting what I was after.

```
SELECT
record,
MAX(CASE WHEN ahv9t_facileforms_subrecords.title = 'Listing ID' then value END) AS Listing,
MAX(CASE WHEN ahv9t_facileforms_subrecords.title = 'Status' then value END) AS Status,
MAX(CASE WHEN ahv9t_facileforms_subrecords.title = 'Resort' then value END) AS Resort,
MAX(CASE WHEN ahv9t_facileforms_subrecords.title = 'Points on Deed' then value END) AS Points,
MAX(CASE WHEN ahv9t_facileforms_subrecords.title = 'Use Year' then value END) AS UseYear,
MAX(CASE WHEN ahv9t_facileforms_subrecords.title = 'Points on Deed' then value END) AS Points,
MAX(CASE WHEN ahv9t_facileforms_subrecords.title = 'Last Years Points' then value END) AS LastYearPoints,
MAX(CASE WHEN ahv9t_facileforms_subrecords.title = 'This Years Points' then value END) AS ThisYearPoints,
MAX(CASE WHEN ahv9t_facileforms_subrecords.title = 'Next Years Points' then value END) AS NextYearPoints,
MAX(CASE WHEN ahv9t_facileforms_subrecords.title = 'Points Available' then value END) AS PointsAvailable,
MAX(CASE WHEN ahv9t_facileforms_subrecords.title = 'Price Per Point' then value END) AS PricePerPoint,
MAX(CASE WHEN ahv9t_facileforms_subrecords.title = 'Price' then value END) AS Price,
MAX(CASE WHEN ahv9t_facileforms_subrecords.title = 'Closing Cost' then value END) AS ClosingCost,
MAX(CASE WHEN ahv9t_facileforms_subrecords.title = 'Annual Dues at Closing' then value END) AS AnnualDuesAtClosing,
MAX(CASE WHEN ahv9t_facileforms_subrecords.title = 'Total Cost' then value END) AS TotalCost,
MAX(CASE WHEN ahv9t_facileforms_subrecords.title = 'Direct Price Per Point' then value END) AS DirectPricePerPoint,
MAX(CASE WHEN ahv9t_facileforms_subrecords.title = 'Savings' then value END) AS Savings,
MAX(CASE WHEN ahv9t_facileforms_subrecords.title = 'Contract Expires' then value END) AS ContractExpires,
MAX(CASE WHEN ahv9t_facileforms_subrecords.title = 'Current Annual Fees' then value END) AS CurrentAnnualFees
FROM ahv9t_facileforms_subrecords
JOIN ahv9t_facileforms_records ON ahv9t_facileforms_records.id = ahv9t_facileforms_subrecords.record
WHERE ahv9t_facileforms_records.form = '12'
GROUP BY record
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use Alias with each table name to distinguish table calls:

FROM ahv9t_facileforms_subrecords ***as A***

JOIN ahv9t_facileforms_records ***as B*** ON ***B***.ahv9t_facileforms_records.id = ***A***.ahv9t_facileforms_subrecords.record

WHERE ***A***.ahv9t_facileforms_records.form = '12'
GROUP BY record

Comment: I am planning on cleaning this up. Was trying not to make it anymore complicated for myself at the moment and just wanted the query working. Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 0):

Because your query lacks properly qualified column names, it is unclear what it is really doing.  That said, I *think* you are trying to do this:

```
SELECT ffs.record,
       MAX(CASE WHEN ffs2.title = 'Listing ID' then ffs2.value END) AS Listing,
       MAX(CASE WHEN ffs2.title = 'Status' then ffs2.value END) AS Status,
       MAX(CASE WHEN ffs2.title = 'Resort' then ffs2.value END) AS Resort,
       MAX(CASE WHEN ffs2.title = 'Points on Deed' then ffs2.value END) AS Points,
       MAX(CASE WHEN ffs2.title = 'Use Year' then ffs2.value END) AS UseYear,
       MAX(CASE WHEN ffs2.title = 'Points on Deed' then ffs2.value END) AS Points,
       MAX(CASE WHEN ffs2.title = 'Last Years Points' then ffs2.value END) AS LastYearPoints,
       MAX(CASE WHEN ffs2.title = 'This Years Points' then ffs2.value END) AS ThisYearPoints,
       MAX(CASE WHEN ffs2.title = 'Next Years Points' then ffs2.value END) AS NextYearPoints,
       MAX(CASE WHEN ffs2.title = 'Points Available' then ffs2.value END) AS PointsAvailable,
       MAX(CASE WHEN ffs2.title = 'Price Per Point' then ffs2.value END) AS PricePerPoint,
       MAX(CASE WHEN ffs2.title = 'Price' then ffs2.value END) AS Price,
       MAX(CASE WHEN ffs2.title = 'Closing Cost' then ffs2.value END) AS ClosingCost,
       MAX(CASE WHEN ffs2.title = 'Annual Dues at Closing' then ffs2.value END) AS AnnualDuesAtClosing,
       MAX(CASE WHEN ffs2.title = 'Total Cost' then ffs2.value END) AS TotalCost,
       MAX(CASE WHEN ffs2.title = 'Direct Price Per Point' then ffs2.value END) AS DirectPricePerPoint,
       MAX(CASE WHEN ffs2.title = 'Savings' then ffs2.value END) AS Savings,
       MAX(CASE WHEN ffs2.title = 'Contract Expires' then ffs2.value END) AS ContractExpires,
       MAX(CASE WHEN ffs2.title = 'Current Annual Fees' then ffs2.value END) AS CurrentAnnualFees
FROM ahv9t_facileforms_subrecords ffs JOIN
     ahv9t_facileforms_subrecords ffs2
     ON ffs.id = ffs2.record
WHERE ffs.form = '12'
GROUP BY ffs.record;
```

In general, you should qualify *all* column names.

That said, I think you can accomplish whatever you want without a self-join.  But you haven't explained what that is, so it is really hard to give more advice.  I would suggest that you ask a *new* question, with a simplified set of data and a clear explanation of what you want to accomplish.