# MySQL Trigger: Update with Inner Join

Tags: mysql

I’m trying to make a AFTER UPDATE Trigger UPDATE a different table by INNER JOINING a VIEW, and cannot get it working.

After an update on Table1, I want to Update Table3 by INNER JOIN it with view1.

I’ve tried multiple variations of:

```
UPDATE T1,T2
INNER JOIN T2 ON T1.C1 = T2.C1
SET T1.C2 = T2.C2,
T2.C3 = expr
WHERE condition
```

Here is my fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a713b9e640a32073f6f8b5f91c38a794

My current code give me the error “mysql Not unique table/alias”.

Edit:

```
-- Trigger

CREATE TRIGGER trigger1
AFTER UPDATE
ON Table1
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN


UPDATE Table3
INNER JOIN view1 ON Table3.id = view1.id
SET
Table3.results1 = view1.results1,
Table3.results2 = view1.results2,
Table3.results3 = view1.results3
WHERE Table3.id = view1.id;


end;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Not unique table/alias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8084571/not-unique-table-alias)

Comment: `UPDATE T1` and not `UPDATE T1,T2`.

Comment: @forpas, I tried that. Gave me the error “can’t update Table, function already in use.

Comment: @ObsidianAge, for someone more experienced it likely does. I only posted after hours of attempts.

Comment: You get the new error because in the fiddle T2 is not a table but a view that selects from Table1. Post here your actual code because as it is your code it has only a syntactical error.

Comment: @forpas , sorry, misread your comment. I’m only playing with this in the fiddle, I wanted to make sure I could get it working. Yes, it’s a view that is created from data in table2 upon conditions in table1. Your saying it should work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message said you can't update using the calling table, but you can circumvent it, by making a temporary table

> ```
> -- Table1
>
> CREATE TABLE Table1 (id INT,session VARCHAR(50), value1 VARCHAR(50),
> value2 VARCHAR(50),value3 VARCHAR(50),status VARCHAR(50));
>
> INSERT INTO Table1 (id,session,value1,value2,value3,status) 
> VALUES
> (1,1,1,2,3,'inactive'),
> (1,2,1,2,3,'inactive'),
> (2,1,1,3,4,'inactive'),
> (2,2,2,3,4,'inactive'),
> (3,1,2,3,2,'active'),
> (3,2,2,3,4,'inactive');
>
> select * from Table1
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
>
> ✓
>
> id | session | value1 | value2 | value3 | status  
> -: | :------ | :----- | :----- | :----- | :-------
>  1 | 1       | 1      | 2      | 3      | inactive
>  1 | 2       | 1      | 2      | 3      | inactive
>  2 | 1       | 1      | 3      | 4      | inactive
>  2 | 2       | 2      | 3      | 4      | inactive
>  3 | 1       | 2      | 3      | 2      | active  
>  3 | 2       | 2      | 3      | 4      | inactive
> ```

> ```
> -- Table2
>
> CREATE TABLE Table2 (value VARCHAR(50),status VARCHAR(50), 
> results varchar(50));
>
> INSERT INTO Table2 (value,status,results) 
> VALUES
> (1,'active','BRK'),
> (2,'inactive','GOOG'),
> (2,'active','HOG'),
> (3,'active','XOM'),
> (1,'inactive','INTC'),
> (4,'inactive','APPL'),
> (3,'active','NKE'),
> (2,'inactive','SBUX'),
> (1,'inactive','BCE'),
> (1,'inactive','S&P'),
> (2,'active','FB'),
> (5,'inactive','FSLY'),
> (1,'inactive','AMZN'),
> (2,'inactive','ARKK'),
> (3,'inactive','AGEN'),
> (4,'inactive','C'),
> (3,'inactive','TSLA'),
> (2,'active','MSFT');
>
> select * from Table2
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
>
> ✓
>
> value | status   | results
> :---- | :------- | :------
> 1     | active   | BRK    
> 2     | inactive | GOOG   
> 2     | active   | HOG    
> 3     | active   | XOM    
> 1     | inactive | INTC   
> 4     | inactive | APPL   
> 3     | active   | NKE    
> 2     | inactive | SBUX   
> 1     | inactive | BCE    
> 1     | inactive | S&P    
> 2     | active   | FB     
> 5     | inactive | FSLY   
> 1     | inactive | AMZN   
> 2     | inactive | ARKK   
> 3     | inactive | AGEN   
> 4     | inactive | C      
> 3     | inactive | TSLA   
> 2     | active   | MSFT
> ```

> ```
> -- Table3
>
> CREATE TABLE Table3 (id INT, session VARCHAR(50), results1 VARCHAR(50),
> results2 VARCHAR(50),results3 VARCHAR(50));
>
> INSERT INTO Table3 (id, session, results1, results2,results3) 
> VALUES
> (1,1,null,null,null),
> (1,2,null,null,null),
> (2,1,null,null,null),
> (2,2,null,null,null),
> (3,1,null,null,null),
> (3,2,null,null,null);
>
> select * from Table3
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
>
> ✓
>
> id | session | results1 | results2 | results3
> -: | :------ | :------- | :------- | :-------
>  1 | 1       | null     | null     | null    
>  1 | 2       | null     | null     | null    
>  2 | 1       | null     | null     | null    
>  2 | 2       | null     | null     | null    
>  3 | 1       | null     | null     | null    
>  3 | 2       | null     | null     | null
> ```

> ```
> -- View1 (Random conditional on Table1)
>
> CREATE VIEW view1 AS
> SELECT Table1.id,Table1.session, (select results from Table2
> where (Table1.status = Table2.status
> and Table1.value1 = Table2.value)
> order by RAND() limit 1) as results1,
>
> (select results from Table2
> where (Table1.status = Table2.status
> and Table1.value2 = Table2.value)
> order by RAND() limit 1) as results2,
>
> (select results from Table2
> where (Table1.status = Table2.status
> and Table1.value3 = Table2.value)
> order by RAND() limit 1) as results3
> from Table1;
>
> select * from view1
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
>
> id | session | results1 | results2 | results3
> -: | :------ | :------- | :------- | :-------
>  1 | 1       | AMZN     | ARKK     | AGEN    
>  1 | 2       | S&P      | SBUX     | AGEN    
>  2 | 1       | S&P      | AGEN     | APPL    
>  2 | 2       | SBUX     | AGEN     | APPL    
>  3 | 1       | FB       | NKE      | HOG     
>  3 | 2       | ARKK     | AGEN     | APPL
> ```

> ```
> -- Trigger
>
> CREATE TRIGGER trigger1
> AFTER UPDATE
> ON Table1
> FOR EACH ROW
> BEGIN
>
>
> UPDATE Table3
> INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM view1) v ON Table3.id = v.id
> SET
> Table3.results1 = v.results1,
> Table3.results2 = v.results2,
> Table3.results3 = v.results3
> WHERE Table3.id = v.id;
>
>
> end;
> ```

> ```
> -- Update
>
> UPDATE Table1
> SET value1 = 2
> WHERE id = 1 and session = 1;
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM Table3;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | session | results1 | results2 | results3
> -: | :------ | :------- | :------- | :-------
>  1 | 1       | ARKK     | ARKK     | TSLA    
>  1 | 2       | ARKK     | ARKK     | TSLA    
>  2 | 1       | BCE      | TSLA     | C       
>  2 | 2       | BCE      | TSLA     | C       
>  3 | 1       | MSFT     | XOM      | HOG     
>  3 | 2       | MSFT     | XOM      | HOG
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=92a93e9c23d1d9882b2fbc93eddf5bb0)*

Comment: Thank you!! I didn’t even know a temporary table was possible. So much to learn.

Comment: is it possible to only update / inner join the rows associated to the ID that was updated in Table1? If I updated rows for ID1 then only those associated rows would join and the others would remain from the last time they were joined. If this is better off as a new question I can create one.

Comment: add to the where clause in the trigger `AND Table3.id = NEW.id` with NEW you have access to athe values of all columns OLD has all the old values before the update, besides you can upvote answers as well

Comment: Perfect! Thanks